# adding stash back to merge on Bit Bucket

Tags: bitbucket

Very new to bit bucket and am running into huge problems. I am part of a team project. We are supposed to finish our section before we commit. I'm working on my section and am not ready to commit. I was asked to pull some new changed made by other members. When I try to do so I get errors saying Your local changes will be overwritten by merge. Please commit or stash them before  merge. So I click on stash it allows me to name them and then afterwards it allows me to do the pull. When I check the files all my work has been written over. When I click on the stash it it lists the one I made. When I try to apply it I get more errors. Merge conflicts on the files that needed to be stashed. What am I doing wrong!!

Comment: Are you all working on the same branch?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I downloaded the Repo that we are all working on. I have a bunch of files I've made changes to, but haven't  committed yet. Some of the other Developers have added commits and I need to add them to my local install. Everything I've tried so far has been to that original Repo I have on local.